# Need help understanding a sentence I came across. Possible ては

Tags: grammar, meaning

I came across this sentence while playing Hatoful Boyfriend. At first I had trouble with the `外見が鳥類では` part. Would I be correct in saying that the use of では in 外見が鳥類では is an example of the　**[ては construction](http://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n2-grammar-%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AF-tewa/)**, and if not could someone please help me understand the grammar behind it?

> はーとふる彼氏では外見が鳥類では脳内再生が困難という方の為に,　登場人物紹介に擬人化版のカットインも御用意しました

Comment: It would be useful to have a little more context in terms of the sentence you're trying to understand here.  Are we talking **て**は or **で**は?  There is a difference between the two...

Comment: The context is when you first play the game, is asks you if you want to display human sprites when you first meet characters instead of the bird sprites. I think its using ては which becomes では with a noun, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Could we see the complete sentence?  I think that では could actually be two particles here, で and は.  I'm not answering below because I'm not 100% sure how to phrase it though.

Comment: That is the complete sentence, the previous sentences are about entering your name and the next is asking if you want to turn the feature on or off.

Comment: oh, duh, I was seeing something else. my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This では is the te-form of the copula だ, followed by the topic marker は. So it's essentially the same では in simple sentences like 私は子供**では**ない. Literally, ～では is "when it's ～, ..." or "if it's ～, ...".

- 外見が鳥類では脳内再生が困難だ
  if the appearance (of the characters) is (that of) avian species, doing 脳内再生 is difficult
- 外見が鳥類では脳内再生が困難(だ)という方
  those who have difficulty in doing 脳内再生 when the characters' appearance is that of avian species
- 外見が鳥類では脳内再生が困難(だ)という方の為に
  for those who have difficulty in doing 脳内再生 with characters that have an avian appearance
- はーとふる彼氏では｛外見が鳥類では脳内再生が困難という方の為に｝、登場人物紹介に擬人化版のカットインも御用意しました。
  In Hatoful Boyfriend, we have also prepared "anthropomorphized" versions of the cut-ins of the characters for those who have difficulty in doing 脳内再生 with characters that have an avian appearance.

Each character in the game is assigned a virtual seiyu, so 脳内再生 here seems to refer to imagining the characters' sweet voice without actually hearing it.

Comment: Ah thank you, I'm glad I correctly guessed that it was ては being used. Thank you so much for your answer!